# File transfer from XBOX 360 to MBA (wifi?)

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro

I have this Spanish lessons on a CD disk!

My MBA does not have a CD drive.

So I use the Xbox to play the CD disk.

However, the Xbox is not very portable :(

I wonder if there is a way to get those files from the Xbox (I saved the files on the xbox harddrive) to my MacBook Air, wirelessly!

Comment: I do not believe this is possible, but you can share the DVD drive of any other Mac computer with an optical drive installed, or buy a compatible external DVD drive for your MBA.

Comment: Sorry, very limited hardware here (no other macs or drives). I only have a HDMI cable that I use to play movies on tv from my MBA. Can I use the HDMI cable for data transfer from xbox to my MBA?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no.  The XBox 360 does not support Disk Sharing.  You would have to get software for the '360 which supported this.

Comment: OK, I can do that, could you provide me with a link.

Comment: This software doesn't exist.